# How does NS2 generate the trace file? And what are the units of the parameters (energy, throughput, delay etc) we get?

Tags: trace, ns2

I know that NS2 runs its core engine and generates the trace file. But in which files are the calculations for generating this trace file done? Also, what are the units (like second, Joule etc) of the parameters we get in the trace file?

Comment: Short: ns2 is one file → The executable `ns`. INFO trace https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+trace+file+format ... → http://nsnam.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/NS-2_Trace_Formats ,,,,,, http://www.grc.upv.es/Links/local/griswoldNS-2%20Traces.htm

Comment: Terms, units https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+trace+terms+:+Power >>> Example http://www.jgyan.com/ns2/energy%20model%20in%20ns2.php ..... More terms, units → https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+trace+terms+units